# IPC Broadcast from class thread back to MainActivity?

Tags: multithreading, ipc, broadcast

I have an SDK class built with a Read Thread. The MainActivity includes the SDK class. I need to pass read messages back from the Read Thread back to the MainActivity. I see similar questions asked but the answers appear to be from MainActivity back to a thread or service. The other question is what context do I use? Can both be the MainActivty context?

Answer (score 0):

I had all the right code in my MainActivity and in my SDK but it needed one extra thing. All it took was to add the following to my AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<application
    <activity
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="company.com.sdk.MY_ACTION_NAME" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```